# Why is this Entity Framework code not saving to the database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

We have a simple *Table per Type* Entity Framework 4.0 model :-

[image]

- ALl classes are all POCO's.
- Post class is `abstract`.
- `Discussion` and `List` are classes are `concretes`, that inherit's from Posts (as shown in the diagram).

When we try to save a `Discussion`, we do the following code :-

`Posts.AddObject(discussion);`

And the Sql Server syntax is in two parts. The second one errors. Notice the sql schema namespace? why is that?
(Code taken from [EFProf](http://efprof.com/))

```
insert [dbo].[Posts]
      ([Subject],
       [UniqueSubject],
       [Content],
       [CreatedOn],
       [ModifiedOn],
       [IsVisible],
       [UserId])
values('Test Subject' /* @0 */,
       'sdfsdfsdfsdfsfdssd' /* @1 */,
       'this is a lot of content - pew pew pew' /* @2 */,
       '23/09/2010 12:22:08 PM +10:00' /* @3 */,
       '23/09/2010 12:22:08 PM +10:00' /* @4 */,
       1 /* @5 */,
       1 /* @6 */)
select [PostId]
from   [dbo].[Posts]
where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       and [PostId] = scope_identity()


insert [XWingModelStoreContainer].[Discussions]
      ([PostId])
values(20132 /* @0 */)
```

**Notice the table name is [XWingModelStoreContainer].[Discussions] ?? Shouldn't that be [dbo].[Discussions] ?? How can we fix this, please?**

.

.

### UPDATE:

Also, here's another screen shot of the properties of our designer .. so u can see that we *thought* that it should be calling [dbo] as that is the default `Database Scheme Name` ..

[image]

and in the Xml `edmx` file.. there's two name'd lines..

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="XWingModel.Store" Alias="Self" 
     Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008"
      xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com.. snip ..."
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ ..snip ..">
    <EntityContainer Name="XWingModelStoreContainer">
.....
```

and ..

```
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.c.. snip .." Space="C-S">
    <Alias Key="Model" Value="XWingModel" />
    <Alias Key="Target" Value="XWingModel.Store" />
    <EntityContainerMapping CdmEntityContainer="XWingEntities" 
        StorageEntityContainer="XWingModelStoreContainer">
.......
```

Does this also help? I have no idea how those names got there (i'm assuming autogenerated) and how do i need to change them? If so, it looks like it's only possible via the xml file .. which is fine .. but feels ... wrong?

Cheers :)

Comment: +1. I'm having a very similar issue.

Comment: I'm hoping @Alex James is still around to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue, and the problem was solved by **making sure the child tables have the Primary Key set**.

Even though the child tables have an FK to the parent table, you still need to set these fields as the PK, otherwise EF does not know how to execute the INSERT on the child tables.

So in your example, try setting **PostId** as the primary key on the **Discussion** table, then refresh your model.

Give that a go.

Comment: Win :) that was it ;) Awesome!! Thanks!